# mkdir no such file or directory syntax error?

Tags: bash, syntax, mkdir

I'm trying to auto-create an auto folder that is unique. Therefore i'm trying to name the folder after a date time stamp.

the code below is what i have already tried.

```
#! /bin/bash
d_space=$(date)
d_nospace= echo ${d_space//[[:blanl:]]/}
echo $d_nospace
mkdir -p "$d_nospace"

WedMay2920:52:47EDT2019
mkdir: cannot create directory '': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I converted the script and output to code format; check it and correct if I got it wrong. Also, is `[[:blanl:]]` actually `[[:blank:]]` in your script? Please be careful to show your code *accurately*; it's much harder to diagnose problems when you have to guess at what the actual code is.

Answer (score 2):

```
d_nospace= echo ${d_space//[[:blanl:]]/}
```

You're missing a `$(...)` capture operator. There shouldn't be a space after the equal sign. And `blanl` should be `blank`.

```
d_nospace=$(echo ${d_space//[[:blank:]]/})
```

Let's get rid of the [useless use of echo](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#echo). There's no need to echo a variable out and then capture the output. Just assign the variable directly.

```
d_nospace=${d_space//[[:blank:]]/}
```

(You don't have to get rid of the spaces, by the way. Directory names can contain whitespace, it's fine.)

Answer (score 0):

```
d_nospace= echo ${d_space//[[:blanl:]]/}
...
mkdir -p "$d_nospace"
```

You're trying to create a directory whose name is the empty string. The "No such file or directory" message is a little misleading. The real problem is that the name is invalid.

A variable assignment must have no spaces before or after the `=` character. You can have a variable assignment as part of another command, for example:

```
foo=bar some_command
```

will execute `some_command` with `$foo` set to `bar`.

So your command invokes the `echo` command with the variable `d_nospace` set to nothing.

As [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56370414/827263) points out, you don't need to use `echo` here -- and in fact it doesn't make sense to do so. If you wanted to delete spaces, you'd write:

```
d_nospace="${d_space//[[:blanl:]]/}"
```

(I haven't checked that for accuracy; shouldn't that be `[[:blank:]]`?

Incidentally, I wouldn't use the output of `date` as a file or directory name. The spaces and colons can cause problems, the output can vary depending on your locale settings, and the result does not sort well.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
now="$(date +%F-%H%M%S)"
mkdir -p "$now"
```

As I write this, the directory name would be `2019-05-29-191819`, which is reasonably human-readable, sorts nicely, and avoids problematic characters.